# Is there a zip archive create/unpack module for Node.js which works/is maintained?

Tags: node.js, zip, node-webkit

I realise this might be a wide/out-of-scope question - but it appears that none of the existing modules for Node are stable/working/useful?

adm-zip is the best I've tried but will sometimes fail to read existing zips, seems to have no support for buffers and frequently writes zips which are invalid?

node-zip (a wrapper for jszip?) failed almost everything I tried with it - it failed to read most zips and has limited features for creating zips and again writes the odd invalid one

The other libraries I found all appear long-dead/unmaintained?

This seems a massive 'hole' in Node's capabilities - esp given that some tools require zip-compatible archive support (an example would be Node Webkit which requires a zipped (not tar.gz) package)

Comment: Try using the native [`zlib`](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html)?  I believe that `node-zip` uses that to do the work.  The doc page I link has examples that you can use to play around and get right to the native library...and track down if the problem is node or something else in the middle.

Comment: zlib can only compress data - it cannot create an archive of files to compress (you'd use tar but I need zip) - I'll sharpen-up the question a bit to clear that issue tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of a partial answer to my own question

[node-archiver](https://github.com/ctalkington/node-archiver) seems a reliable tool to zip files - I've not seen any corruption issues, it supports streams/pipes and offers zip and gz compression

Example: I can open a tar.gz, pipe it into zlib's gunzip and pipe that straight into archiver - which is great

```
request("http://pathtomytar.gz").pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(tar.Parse()).on("entry",function(e) {
var b = new Buffer(e["_header"].size)
var boff = 0
e.on("data", function (d) {
  d.copy(b,boff)
  boff += d.length
).on("end",function() {
  archive.append(b, { name: e.path})
})
```

})

If there's a library/module which opens zips and pipes them as above - it would complete the set but I've yet to find a reliable one - more news if I do